# RestSharp string

Tags: c#, .net, postman, restsharp

I am making a program using C# .NET Core 3.1 That will print a message to slack channel I created 
The problem is : I cannot get the right format to insert ($"{DateTime.Now} : {msg}\n") in the request.addParameter line.

the current code simply prints "msg" instead of the variable msg

```
using System;
using LoggerCore;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace SlackChannel
{
    public class SlackLogger : BaseLogger
    {

        protected override void SubClassLog(string msg,LogOutput logOutput)
        {


            if (logOutput == LogOutput.OutputToAll || logOutput == LogOutput.OutputToSlack)
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xoxp-1016176172148-1005162966131-1005208408259-f08d87bb747a04f66f4daa1846fe7659");
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                request.AddParameter("text/plain", "{\n\t\"text\": \"msg\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Correct this line. request.AddParameter("text/plain", "{\n\t\"text\": \"msg\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody); This is adding the msg as text not msg variable

Comment: yes I know this line is wrong but how do I correct it ? all escape characters are not working

Comment: Change it to  request.AddParameter("text/plain", "{\"text\": \""+msg+"\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);